# How to make an element look resizable

Tags: css, resize, controls, outline

I was trying to create a look similar to how Adobe Illustrator looks when you are resizing or moving an element. I was unable to find helpful sources on the matter of how to achieve this via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0syoecg/)

HTML:

```
<div id='input_container' class='resizeStyles'>
  <label>Label:</label>
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#input_container{position:relative; outline:#333 dashed 2px;}

.resizeStyles:before, .resizeStyles:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:6px;
    border-width:6px;
    border-style:none dotted;
    border-color:#333;
}
.resizeStyles:before{top:-4px; left:-6px;}
.resizeStyles:after{bottom:-4px; right:-6px;}
```

**Note**: I am generating elements via jQuery, so it made sense for me to add & remove a class `.resizeStyles` to attach styles to.

Comment: The jsFiddle link is just jsFiddle.net

Comment: Oops, I'll fix that. Thank you.